# Ruby on rails dropdown box

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html-select

I just wrote my first ruby on rails application and I'm kinda stuck. I have a library database with authors, books and categories.  a book belong to an author and category. SO now when creating a book I would like to select an author and category from a list. How do I go about doing that. I'm new on ruby so any help would be appreciated. For now the book only has the name column.

Here is the books class or model:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :author
  belongs_to :category
  attr_accessible :name
  validates :name, :presence => true
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your books form use following select field as:

```
<%= f.select :author_id, Author.all.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] } %>
<%= f.select :category_id, Category.all.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] } %>
```

For more details of association alse see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: Thanks for giving me directions. How do i create the new record in the controller because i currently have the following lines of code but the author_id and category_id are not the correct ones.
book = Book.new(params[:book])
respond_to do |format|
      if book.save

Answer (score 0):

It likely be something like in your view:

```
<% form_for :book do |f|%>
 <% f.text_field :name %>
 <% f.select :author_id, options_for_select( @authors.all.map{|a| a.name, a.id } %>
 <% f.select :category_id, options_for_select( @categories.all.map{|c| c.name, c.id} ) %>
<% end %>
```

and something like

```
@authors = Author.all
@categories = Category.all
```

in your controller